# How to serialize some properties of a WPF custom control to element instead of attribute

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, serialization

I'm working with VS2015 and WPF on a mask designer in which my customers can design masks for an application.

They can add custom controls (which i defined) to these masks and serialize the masks to XML while saving, so that the masks can be reloaded when it's needed to make adjustments to them.

One of my custom controls inherits of Label and i have added a property called "DisplayText".

Normally that property is serialized - like all the other properties - to an XML-attribute.

But now i have the problem, that in the data of my customers are some values like "Q{a}" which means a big "Q" followed by a subscripted small "a".

So i wanted to replace "{a}" in the XML by using the sub-tag while reloading a mask, but this doesn't work with attributes just XML-elements.

```html
<sub>a</sub>
```

Next i tried to redefine the property DisplayText in my custom control like that:

```
[XmlElement("DisplayText")]
public string DisplayText
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(DisplayTextProperty); }
    set { SetValue(DisplayTextProperty, value); }
}
```

But when i save a mask with such a control DisplayText is not serialized to an element.

And when i try to manipulate the XML and replace the attribute by an element i get the error message that DisplayText is unknown.

How can i resolve that problem?

Here a test example how the XML shall look like (coorect me if i'm wrong):

```
<Grid Name=\"grdMaskDesigner\" Grid.Column=\"0\" Grid.Row=\"1\" xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\" xmlns:pccl=\"clr-namespace:P16CustomControlLibrary;assembly=P16CustomControlLibrary\">
  <ScrollViewer>
    <Canvas Name=\"maskDesignerPanel\" Height=\"3500\" AllowDrop=\"True\" Visibility=\"Visible\">
      <Canvas.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource=\"pack://application:,,,/P16Admintool;component/pictures/CanvasBackground.png\" ViewportUnits=\"Absolute\" Viewport=\"0,0,10,10\" Stretch=\"None\" TileMode=\"Tile\" />
      </Canvas.Background>
      <pccl:CustomLabel Name=\"RTB_1\" Width=\"80\" Height=\"40\" ToolTip=\"RTB1\" Canvas.Left=\"80\" Canvas.Top=\"60\">
        <DisplayText>Q_{a} =</DisplayText>
        <pccl:CustomLabel.ContextMenu>
          <ContextMenu Placement=\"MousePoint\">
            <MenuItem Header=\"Edit\" />
            <MenuItem Header=\"Remove\" />
            <MenuItem Header=\"Copy\" />
          </ContextMenu>
        </pccl:CustomLabel.ContextMenu>
      </pccl:CustomLabel>
    </Canvas>
  </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

And this is the method with which i serialize the Grid panel on which the controls are placed:

```
public string SerializeControlToXaml(FrameworkElement element)
{
    var elementToXaml = new StringBuilder();
    var settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
    settings.Indent = true;
    settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
    var serializationManager = new XamlDesignerSerializationManager(XmlWriter.Create(elementToXaml, settings));
    serializationManager.XamlWriterMode = XamlWriterMode.Expression;
    XamlWriter.Save(element, serializationManager);
    var xaml = elementToXaml.ToString();

    return xaml;
}
```

Comment: Try :settings.Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);

Comment: @jdweng : Thank You but the result is still the same. DisplayText is still an attribute not an element.

Comment: Further i have found out now that it doesn't help me to use XmlElement because the sup- and sub-tags cannot be used inside a value. When i try to set the XML by a prepared string i get the error "Value must be followed by end tag". So the element value "U<sub>a</sub>" don't work.